# Change "Rating" field in Gallery View card

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, rating, gallery-view

In SharePoint Online I have a list with the "Rating Settings" set to "Star Ratings".  In a List view, the "Rating" field shows up with stars in a column, and the user can click the appropriate number of stars to rate the item.

In a Gallery view, the "rating" field shows up with stars in the item's card (see image below).  However, the user CANNOT click the stars to rate the item.  Is there a way (JSON code, something else) to allow user to rate an item while in gallery view?

[image: Sample card showing the rating symbol]

Comment: The classic issue with the defaultClick action in JSON of gallery view - you will have to remove it from the JSON. Refer [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/301298/json-formatting-sharepoint-list-link-inside-gallery/301299#301299). Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP - You are unto something, but not quite.  I deleted the `sp-card-defaultClickButton` now, when I hover over the star rating the cursor changes to a hand, implying it could be clicked.  However, clicking over the rating does nothing

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP - I played around with this some more.  Looking carefully at the JSON that gets autogenerated with the rating column, there is no associated click or button actions.

Answer (score 0):

After significant sleuthing, I don't believe this can be done.

When "Ratings" are turned on, they are captured in four columns, all of which get automatically updated when the rating is updated in a standard view.  The four columns (with their internal names) are:

- `Rating (0-5)` -- `AverageRating`
- `Number of Ratings` -- `RatingCount`
- `Rated By` -- `RatedBy`
- `User ratings` -- `Ratings`

The `RatedBy` field is of type `UserMulti`, and the `Ratings` column is of type `note` .  Both of these are hidden.

I created a CustomRowAction, which is able to update the `AverageRating` and `RatingCount` columns. However, because the `RatedBy` and `Ratings` columns are hidden they cannot be added to the view, and therefore manipulating them with JSON is questionable.  `Ratings` can actually be displayed, I can do a `=length(RatedBy)` but cannot display the contents of `RatedBy`.

More importantly, as far as I can tell, there is no way to update these columns via the CustomRowAction.